# Regex to extract URLs from href attribute in HTML with Python

Tags: regex, url

Considering a string as follows:

```
string = "<p>Hello World</p><a href="http://example.com">More Examples</a><a href="http://2.example">Even More Examples</a>"
```

How could I, with Python, extract the URLs, inside the anchor tag's href? Something like:

```
>>> url = getURLs(string)
>>> url
['http://example.com', 'http://2.example']
```

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with regexp. Look for a HTML parser, that can extract the `href` value for you.

Comment: @Judge John Deed: [better be lazy](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760588/how-do-you-extract-a-url-from-a-string-using-python/31952097#31952097

Answer (score 182, accepted):

```
import re

url = '<p>Hello World</p><a href="http://example.com">More Examples</a><a href="http://2.example">Even More Examples</a>'

urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', url)

>>> print urls
['http://example.com', 'http://2.example']
```

Comment: In any sort of normal scraping where the text portion of the href is also a link rather than descriptive text, this just gives duplicates.

Comment: For those modifying this regex, note that the '-' in the [$-_@.&+] is acting as a range operator and not a character. This means certain chairs (e.g., ',') are represented more than once.

Comment: This regex does not consider URL fragments (the # suffix).

Comment: How can this be used to catch URLs without `http` ? Like `www.google.com` or `google.com`

Comment: Ditto for other schemes, e.g. `tel:+44123456` or `mailto:foo@example.org`

Comment: It doesn't work for following TEXT: `"http://lubimyczytac.pl/ksiazka/57710/nowy-umysl-cesarza-o-komputerach-umysle-i-prawach-fizyki':"`

Comment: hey @Jan-Philip Gehrcke do you know how to do it now with URL fragments?

Comment: What does the % sign do in the regex? (?:%[0-9
Is it a wildcard? I searched docs for regex python3.6, it's not lookahead or lookbehind

Comment: @devssh It's a percent sign. It matches a percent sign. That's it.

Comment: This regex is horrible. I'll take the liberty to update it.

Comment: This also misses most of `http://example2.com/page.asp?key=val&key2=x+y`

Comment: Does not work for twitter shortened urls

Answer (score 68):

The best answer is...

#### Don't use a regex

The expression in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6883094/577088) misses many cases. Among other things, *URLs can have unicode characters in them*. The regex you want is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url), and after looking at it, you may conclude that you don't really want it after all. The most correct version is *ten-thousand characters long*.

Admittedly, if you were starting with plain, unstructured text with a bunch of URLs in it, then you might need that ten-thousand-character-long regex. But **if your input is structured, use the structure**. Your stated aim is to "extract the URL, inside the anchor tag's href." Why use a ten-thousand-character-long regex when you can do something much simpler?

#### Parse the HTML instead

For many tasks, using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) will be far faster and easier to use:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
>>> html = Soup(s, 'html.parser')           # Soup(s, 'lxml') if lxml is installed
>>> [a['href'] for a in html.find_all('a')]
['http://example.com', 'http://2.example']
```

If you prefer not to use external tools, you can also directly use Python's own built-in HTML parsing library. Here's a really simple subclass of [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) that does exactly what you want:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, output_list=None):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        if output_list is None:
            self.output_list = []
        else:
            self.output_list = output_list
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            self.output_list.append(dict(attrs).get('href'))
```

Test:

```
>>> p = MyParser()
>>> p.feed(s)
>>> p.output_list
['http://example.com', 'http://2.example']
```

You could even create a new method that accepts a string, calls `feed`, and returns `output_list`. This is a vastly more powerful and extensible way than regular expressions to extract information from HTML.

Comment: What's all the `__init__` and `self` stuff?

Comment: Beautiful is great is you need to parse href or src as asked in the initial question and should be the accepted answer, but beware it won't help to find URL in strings.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though. The question is about the format of URLs, not how to parse HTML.

Comment: @AlSweigart, I think it's reasonable to say that the body of the question asks about parsing HTML.

Comment: @AlSweigart, thanks for editing the title. I was thinking about this and realized that by my own logic, I should actually edit the title. Then I saw that you had done so already!

Comment: @senderle I'm with you on not using regex for this, but your parser misses so many urls in my corpus, specially shortened urls.

Comment: @pedrambashiri, if it's missing urls that are in `<a>` tags, then that indicates a bug in the underlying Python library. It is guaranteed not to capture urls elsewhere — but that's not what the question asks for.

Comment: No they are not in <a> tag. My corpus is an aggregation of the posts on Reddit and urls are shortened in most cases. An example is 'https://discord.gg/CVaoq4x'