# How to remove words containing a substring in a python string?

Tags: python

As I'm consuming Twitter API, I got several strings (tweets) containing links, that's it substrings beggining with `'http://'`.

How can I get rid of such links, that's it, I want to remove the *whole word*.

Let's say I have:

```
'Mi grupo favorito de CRIMINALISTICA. Ultima clase de cuatrimestre http://t.co/Ad2oWDNd4u'
```

And I want to obtain:

```
'Mi grupo favorito de CRIMINALISTICA. Ultima clase de cuatrimestre'
```

Such substrings may appear anywhere along the string

Comment: Will they appear only at the end?

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm already used to see you around :P They might not only appear at the end

Comment: Also, will there be a space after the URLs?

Comment: There might be, @thefourtheye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace all links with an empty string:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')
>>> s = 'Mi grupo favorito de CRIMINALISTICA. Ultima clase de cuatrimestre http://t.co/Ad2oWDNd4u'
>>> pattern.sub('', s)
'Mi grupo favorito de CRIMINALISTICA. Ultima clase de cuatrimestre '
```

It replaces all the links in the string anywhere inside it:

```
>>> s = "I've used google https://google.com and found a regular expression pattern to find links here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python"
>>> pattern.sub('', s)
"I've used google  and found a regular expression pattern to find links here "
```

Regular expression was taken from this thread:

- [Regex to find urls in string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it as:

```
s[:s.index('http://')-1]
```

If it doesn't always appear at the end, you can do:

```
your_list = s.split()
i = 0
while i < len(your_list):
    if your_list[i].startswith('http://'):
        del your_list[i]
    else:
        i+=1
s = ' '.join(your_list)
```