# How to click the link in email body and how to spot out the link using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

How to spot out the link and click the link from email body.

```
${FIELD NAME}=    ImapLibrary.Get Links From Email    ${latest}
${mailbody}=    ImapLibrary.Get Email Body    ${latest}
${HTML}=    ImapLibrary.Open Link From Mail    ${latest}
```

But when I give "Get Email Body", I'm able to get total content in email body. How to spot out the links from there and how to click from there?

Answer (score 0):

To find links you need to use regexps. For example this Stackoverflow question answers how to find urls in text: [Regex to find urls in string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python)

It looks like this in Robot Framework:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           re

*** Variables ***
${mailbody}   this is mail body http://www.stackoverflow.com/ foobar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288261/how-to-click-the-link-in-email-body-and-how-to-spot-out-the-link-using-robot-fra

*** Settings ***
Library           re

*** Variables ***
${mailbody}   this is mail body http://www.stackoverflow.com/ foobar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288261/how-to-click-the-link-in-email-body-and-how-to-spot-out-the-link-using-robot-fra
${url regexp}    http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+

*** Test Cases ***
Get Urls
    @{lines}=    re.findall    ${url regexp}    ${mailbody}     
    Log Many    @{lines}
```

You cannot really click the links, instead you should use Selenium2Library to open them in browser.

Comment: thank u so much.. i m able to get all links . Now how to point out the link. if it displays 10 links .  open browser  firefox                                                                                                                           Go to   @{lines}[9]. can i give like this . to go via that link

Comment: You can open them in browser with Selenium2Library: https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library

Comment: I can never remember correct syntax for Selenium2Library so I have this link in my browser toolbar: http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html. Correct command is: "Open Browser    @{lines}[9]    Firefox

Comment: can log many be stored in a variable like this                                          ${values}=     Log Many     @{lines}

Comment: I don't think so. I don't understand what you are trying to do, please open a new question.

Comment: when i give Open Browser @{lines}[9]   it gives error Variable '@{lines}[9]' not found

Comment: I  m getting list of links using logmany function.How to open 8 th link in a new browser.

Comment: @{lines} is a Python list and the first item is @{lines}[0]

Comment: Open Browser @{lines}[9]  it works.. thank u so much