# extract URL from string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to extract a full URL from a string.

My code is:

```
import re
data = "ahahahttp://www.google.com/a.jpg>hhdhd"
print re.match(r'(ftp|http)://.*\.(jpg|png)$', data)
```

Output:

```
None
```

Expected Output

```
http://www.google.com/a.jpg
```

I found so many questions on StackOverflow, but none worked for me.
I have seen many posts and this is not a duplicate. Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: This has been answered lots of time, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python

Answer (score 4):

You were close!

Try this instead:

```
r'(ftp|http)://.*\.(jpg|png)'
```

You can visualize this [here](https://regex101.com/r/kB5iS0/1).

I would also make this non-greedy like this:

```
r'(ftp|http)://.*?\.(jpg|png)'
```

You can visualize this greedy vs. non-greedy behavior [here](https://regex101.com/r/kB5iS0/2) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/kB5iS0/3).

By default, `.*` will match as much text as possible, but you want to match as little text as possible.

Your `$` anchors the match at the end of the line, but the end of the URL is not the end of the line, in your example.

Another problem is that you're using `re.match()` and not `re.search()`. Using `re.match()` starts the match at the beginning of the string, and `re.search()` searches anywhere in the string. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for more information.

Comment: upvote for the visualize. however, it is not valid in some sense. For ex, http://http://.xjpg.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the visualizations so the original regex correction is shown, as well as the greedy vs. non-greedy match. And yes, this isn't a great regex to match URLs in all forms, but that's answered elsewhere, and my goal is to show what the main problems with OPs regex are for the examples given :)

Comment: Thankyou, I got it now!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use search instead of match.

```
import re
data = "ahahahttp://www.google.com/a.jpg>hhdhd"
url=re.search('(ftp|http)://.*\.(jpg|png)', data)
if url:
   print url.group(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Find the start of the url by using find(http:// , ftp://) . Find the end of url using find(jpg , png). Now get the substring

```
data = "ahahahttp://www.google.com/a.jpg>hhdhd"
start = data.find('http://')
kk = data[start:]
end = kk.find('.jpg')
print kk[0:end+4]
```