# python, remove link from string

Tags: python, string, parsing, filter

How can the link from this string be removed

```
s=' hello how are you www.ford.com today '
```

so that the output is

```
s='hello how are you today'
```

Comment: Are you asking for a general solution or just for that string, because urls can be extremely diverse

Comment: a solution that can handle any sub-string in the form of www.something.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following list comprehension, which omits words of the pattern `www._____.com`:

```
' '.join(item for item in s.split() if not (item.startswith('www.') and item.endswith('.com')) and len(item) > 7) #the len(item) is to make sure that words like www.com, which aren't real URLs, aren't removed
```

---

```
>>> s=' hello how are you www.ford.com today '
>>> ' '.join(item for item in s.split() if not (item.startswith('www.') and item.endswith('.com') and len(item) > 7))
'hello how are you today'
>>>
```

Comment: That is a very elegant and readable solution

Comment: @Natecat not sure if you're being sarcastic :)

Comment: what if the string is s=' hello how are youwww.ford.comtoday ', and the words within the sting have no space between the link? @A.J.

Comment: @abcla My answer addresses this case

Comment: Wouldn't `www.com`, which is not a URL, get removed by this?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

While you can certainly use `strings` methods, I prefer the regular expression based approach. It can handle spaces between words.

```
import re

s = " hello www.something.com there bobby"
s = re.sub(r'www\.\S+\.com', '',s)
print(s) # hello  there bobby
s = "hello www. begins and .com ends"
s = re.sub(r'www\.\S+\.com', '',s)
print(s) # hello www. begins and .com ends
```

Comment: This fails on the same condition as mine as Gerrat mentioned

Comment: @Natecat should work with spaces between the phrases now.

Comment: if ```s = "hello www. begins and .com ends"```,and I also want to print ```hello  there bobby```,so how can I  remove single whitespace within the url link.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good situation for a regex substitution.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ' hello how are you www.ford.com today www.example.co.jp '
>>> re.sub(r'\s*(?:https?://)?www\.\S*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}\s*', ' ', s).strip()
'hello how are you today'
```

The above finds any string that starts with potential whitespace, then possibly `https://` or `http://`, then `www.`, then any non-whitespace characters, then `.` followed by 2-5 alphabetical characters, then potential whitespace. It replaces such strings with a single space, and then removes leading and trailing whitespace from the result.

Note that this is a naive example of a URL, as defined by your specific example. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python) for a regex with a more complete definition of what constitutes a URL.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deal with the case where there is no space around the url, you can use the string split method like this:

```
if ".com" in s:
    s=''.join((s.split("www.")[0], " ", s.split(".com")[1]))
```

Comment: Your expression fails on sentences like: `The prefix www. often starts a url, while .com ends it`