# Iterate and replace words in lines of a tuple python

Tags: python, regex, loops, replace, tuples

I want to iterate through this tuple and for each line, iterate through the words to find and replace some words (internet addresses, precisely) using regex while leaving them as lines.

```
aList=
[
  "being broken changes people, \nand rn im missing the old me", 
  "@SaifAlmazroui @troyboy621 @petr_hruby you're all missing the point", 
  "#News #Detroit Detroit water customer receives shutoff threat over missing 10 cents: - Theresa Braxton is a l... T.CO/CHPBRVH9WKk", 
  "@_EdenRodwell \ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29ahh I love you!! Missing u, McDonald's car park goss soon please \u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0fxxxxx", 
  "This was my ring tone, before I decided change was good and missing a call was insignificant T.CO?BUXLVZFDWQ", 
  "want to go on holiday again, missing the sun\ud83d\ude29\u2600\ufe0f"
]
```

This code below almost does that, but it breaks the list into words separated by lines:

```
i=0
while i<len(aList):
    for line in aList[i].split():
        line = re.sub(r"^[http](.*)\/(.*)$", "", line)
        print (line)
        i+=1
```

I'd love to have results as with the exception of the internet addresses in each line:

```
[
  "being broken changes people, \nand rn im missing the old me", 
  "@SaifAlmazroui @troyboy621 @petr_hruby you're all missing the point", 
  "#News #Detroit Detroit water customer receives shutoff threat over missing 10 cents: - Theresa Braxton is a ", 
  "@_EdenRodwell \ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29ahh I love you!! Missing u, McDonald's car park goss soon please \u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0fxxxxx", 
  "This was my ring tone, before I decided change was good and missing a call was insignificant", 
  "want to go on holiday again, missing the sun\ud83d\ude29\u2600\ufe0f"
]
```

Thanks

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Python doesn't work with plus plus, you have to do plus equals.

Comment: That was a typo error for i++, bpachev and I've corrected that. John1024, The code runs without that typo error and I'm not allowed to put internet addresses in the question. The examples of the addresses are(T.CO?BUXLVZFDWQ); I've put them in all caps.

Comment: regex `[http]` means 1 character which is either h, t or p. regex `http` means 4 characters which are in order, h, t, t and then p.

Comment: Yeah, Aprillion. I figured that out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this:

```
re.sub(r"^[http](.*)\/(.*)$", "", line)
```

it looks to me as if you expect that all your URLs will be at the end of the line.  In that case, try:

```
[re.sub('http://.*', '', s) for s in aList]
```

Here, `http://` matches anything that starts with `http://`.  `.*` matches everything that follows.

#### Example

Here is your list with some URLs added:

```
aList = [
  "being broken changes people, \nand rn im missing the old me",
  "@SaifAlmazroui @troyboy621 @petr_hruby you're all missing the point",
  "#News #Detroit Detroit water customer receives shutoff threat over missing 10 cents: - Theresa Braxton is a http://example.com/CHPBRVH9WKk",
  "@_EdenRodwell ahh I love you!! Missing u, McDonald's car park goss soon please xxxxx",
  "This was my ring tone, before I decided change was good and missing a call was insignificant http://example.com?BUXLVZFDWQ",
  "want to go on holiday again, missing the sun"
  ]
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> [re.sub('http://.*', '', s) for s in aList]
['being broken changes people, \nand rn im missing the old me',
 "@SaifAlmazroui @troyboy621 @petr_hruby you're all missing the point",
 '#News #Detroit Detroit water customer receives shutoff threat over missing 10 cents: - Theresa Braxton is a ',
 "@_EdenRodwell ahh I love you!! Missing u, McDonald's car park goss soon please xxxxx",
 'This was my ring tone, before I decided change was good and missing a call was insignificant ',
 'want to go on holiday again, missing the sun']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think I get what you're going for

```
newlist = [re.sub(r"{regex}", "", line) for line in alist]
```

Should iterate through a list of strings and replace any strings that match your regex pattern with an empty string using a python list comprehension

side note:

Looking closer at your regex it looks like its not doing what you think its doing
I would look at this stack over flow post about matching urls in regex

[Regex to find urls in string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python)

Comment: This works, but iterates through the lines only, not through each word in a line. So it just replaces a whole line that is just an internet addresses.