# How to extract a link from the embedded link with python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDoctorTaniya%2Fposts%2F1906676949620646&width=500" width="500" height="482" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I want to extract link:

```
www.facebook.com/DoctorTaniya/posts/1906676949620646
```

How to write a python script to do this?

Comment: You need regular expressions.

Comment: @hallazzang not necessarily since it is in HTML, normal HTML parsers can work too.

Comment: @hallazzang I figured that out but could not write the regex needed.

Comment: @MoonCheesez yes but even with html parsers, still regular expression is a good choice for extracting link from `iframe[src]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to use [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

The text to parse is an `iframe` tag with the `src`. You are trying the retrieve the url after `href=` and before `&width` in the `src` attribute.

After that, you would need to decode the url back to text.

First, you throw it into beautiful soup and get the attribute out of it:

```
text = '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDoctorTaniya%2Fposts%2F1906676949620646&width=500" width="500" height="482" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

src_attribute = soup.find("iframe")["src"]
```

And then there you could use regex here or use `.split()` (quite hacky):

```
# Regex
link = re.search('.*?href=(.*)?&', src_attribute).group(1)

# .split()
link = src_attribute.split("href=")[1].split("&")[0]
```

Lastly, you would need to decode the url using [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
link = urllib2.unquote(link)
```

and you are done!

So the resulting code would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

text = '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDoctorTaniya%2Fposts%2F1906676949620646&width=500" width="500" height="482" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

src_attribute = soup.find("iframe")["src"]

# Regex
link = re.findall('.*?href=(.*)?&', src_attribute)[0]
# .split()
link = src_attribute.split("href=")[1].split("&")[0]

link = urllib2.unquote(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883049/regex-to-find-urls-in-string-in-python) is some useful information about Regex to find urls in Python.

If all the urls you code will work with start right after a `.php?href=` then you can create a loop that stops when the `?href=` is found and split the string.

Or you can use `$_GET[]` and print it, [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173452/can-python-and-php-work-together) is other post you might want to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

string = '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDoctorTaniya%2Fposts%2F1906676949620646&width=500" width="500" height="482" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>'

m = re.search( r'href=https%3A%2F%2F(.*)&width', string)
str2 = m.group(1)
str2.replace('%2F', '/')
```

Output

```
>>> str2.replace('%2F', '/')
'www.facebook.com/DoctorTaniya/posts/1906676949620646'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `BeautifulSoup`, `re` and `urllib`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, urllib

html = """
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDoctorTaniya%2Fposts%2F1906676949620646&width=500" width="500" height="482" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
<p>some other rubbish here</p>
"""

# da soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

# href, (anything not &) afterwards
rx = re.compile(r'href=([^&]+)')

for iframe in soup.findAll('iframe'):
    link = urllib.unquote(rx.search(iframe['src']).group(1))
    print(link)
    # https://www.facebook.com/DoctorTaniya/posts/1906676949620646
```

It parses the `DOM`, looks for iframes, analyzes these with a regular expression and unquotes the found URL. Thus, you do not act on the `DOM` directly.