# Searching for URL's in tweets via Python Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Haven't been able to find much on this. Is there a way to use tweepy (or if you can think of a better way that still utilizes tweepy but with something else) to search for tweets that have a url in them? I don't believe the API.search function allows you to pass html attributes (for instance an a would be perfect) or by type. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you try to search for `example.com` ? That should return all the Tweets which have that URL in them.

Comment: @TerenceEden Thanks for the reply, but I'm not trying to search for a specific link. Literally just trying to find all tweets containing URL's in them.

Comment: Then do a search for "t.co" - that will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this [Regex to find urls in string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6883094/7004027)

---

You can still use **api.search()** and match them with a **Regex** that finds URLs

**NOTE:** I haven't tested it & i don't have used Tweepy for a while now, so there is a chance this might not work!