# Extract URL from webpage and save to disk

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to write a script to automaotmcally query [sci-hub.io](http://sci-hub.io) with an article's title and save a PDF copy of the articles full text to my computer with a specific file name.

To do this I have written the following code:

```
url = "http://sci-hub.io/"
data = read_csv("C:\\Users\\Sangeeta's\\Downloads\\distillersr_export (1).csv")
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    try:
        print('http://sci-hub.io/' + str(row['DOI']))
        res = requests.get('http://sci-hub.io/' + str(row['DOI']))
        print(res.content)
    except:
        print('NO DOI: ' + str(row['ref']))
```

This opens a CSV file with a list of DOI's and names of the file to be saved. For each DOI, it then queries sci-hub.io for the full-text. The presented page embeds the PDF in however I am now unsure how to extract the URL for the PDF and save it to disk.

An example of the page can be seen in the image below:

[image]

In this image, the desired URL is http://dacemirror.sci-hub.io/journal-article/3a257a9ec768d1c3d80c066186aba421/pajno2010.pdf.

How can I automatically extract this URL and then save the PDF file to disk?

When I print res.content, I get this:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <title></title>\n        <meta charset="UTF-8">\n        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">\n    </head>\n    <body>\n    <style type = "text/css">\n        body {background-color:#F0F0F0}\n        div {overflow: hidden; position: absolute;}\n        #top {top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:50px;font-size:14px} /* 40px */\n        #content {top:50px;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%}\n        p {margin:0;padding:10px}\n        a {font-size:12px;font-family:sans-serif}\n        a.target {font-weight:normal;color:green;margin-left:10px}\n        a.reopen {font-weight:normal;color:blue;text-decoration:none;margin-left:10px}\n        iframe {width:100%;height:100%}\n        \n        p.agitation {padding-top:5px;font-size:20px;text-align:center}\n        p.agitation a {font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;color:green}\n\n        .banner {position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:400px;left:0px;width:300px;height:225px;\n                 border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 5px;\n                 text-align:center;font-size:18px}\n        .banner img {border:0}\n        \n        p.donate {padding:0;margin:0;padding-top:5px;text-align:center;background:green;height:40px}\n        p.donate a {color:white;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px}\n\n        #save {position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:180px;left:8px;width:210px;height:36px;\n                 border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 5px;\n                 text-align:center;font-size:18px;background:#F0F0F0;color:#333}\n\n        #save a {text-decoration:none;color:white;font-size:inherit;color:#666}\n\n        #save p { margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 8px}\n\n        #reload {position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:240px;left:8px;width:210px;height:36px;\n                 border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 5px;\n                 text-align:center;font-size:18px;background:#F0F0F0;color:#333}\n\n        #reload a {text-decoration:none;color:white;font-size:inherit;color:#666}\n\n        #reload p { margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 8px}\n\n\n        #saveastro {position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:360px;left:8px;width:230px;height:70px;\n                    border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px #ccc; background: white; text-align:center}\n        #saveastro p { margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 16px}\n        \n        \n        #donate {position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:170px;right:16px;width:220px;height:36px;\n                 border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 5px;\n                 text-align:center;font-size:18px;background:white;color:#333}\n        \n        #donate a {text-decoration:none;color:green;font-size:inherit}\n\n        #donatein {position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:220px;right:16px;width:220px;height:36px;\n                 border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 5px;\n                 text-align:center;font-size:18px;background:green;color:#333}\n\n        #donatein a {text-decoration:none;color:white;font-size:inherit}\n        \n        #banner {position:absolute;z-index:9999;top:50%;left:45px;width:250px;height:250px; padding: 0; border: solid 1px white; border-radius: 4px}\n        \n    </style>\n    \n        \n    \n    <script type = "text/javascript">\n        window.onload = function() {\n            var url = document.getElementById(\'url\');\n            if (url.innerHTML.length > 77)\n                url.innerHTML = url.innerHTML.substring(0,77) + \'...\';\n        };\n    </script>\n    <div id = "top">\n        \n        <p class="agitation" style = "padding-top:12px">\n            \xd0\xa1\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0 Sci-Hub \xd0\xb2 \xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd1\x85 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x8f\xd1\x85 \xe2\x86\x92  <a target="_blank" href="https://vk.com/sci_hub">vk.com/sci_hub</a>\n        </p>\n        \n    </div>\n    \n    <div id = "content">\n        <iframe src = "http://moscow.sci-hub.io/202d9ebdfbb8c0c56964a31b2fdfe8e9/roerdink2016.pdf" id = "pdf"></iframe>\n    </div>\n    \n    <div id = "donate">\n        <p><a target = "_blank" href = "//sci-hub.io/donate">\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x82 &rarr;</a></p>\n    </div>\n    <div id = "donatein">\n        <p><a target = "_blank" href = "//sci-hub.io/donate">support the project &rarr;</a></p>\n    </div>\n    <div id = "save">\n        <p><a href = # onclick = "location.href=\'http://moscow.sci-hub.io/202d9ebdfbb8c0c56964a31b2fdfe8e9/roerdink2016.pdf?download=true\'">\xe2\x87\xa3 \xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd1\x85\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c\xd1\x8e</a></p>\n    </div>\n    <div id = "reload">\n        <p><a href = "//sci-hub.io/reload/10.1016/j.anai.2016.01.022" target = "_blank">&#8635; \xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe</a></p>\n    </div>\n    \n        \n<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter --> <script type="text/javascript"> (function (d, w, c) { (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() { try { w.yaCounter10183018 = new Ya.Metrika({ id:10183018, clickmap:true, trackLinks:true, accurateTrackBounce:true, ut:"noindex" }); } catch(e) { } }); var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], s = d.createElement("script"), f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); }; s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true; s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js"; if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") { d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false); } else { f(); } })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks"); </script> <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/10183018?ut=noindex" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript> <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->\n    </body>\n</html>\n'
```

Which does include the URL, however I am unsure how to extract it.

**Update:**

I am now able to extract the URL but when I try to access the page with the PDF (through urllib.request) I get a 403 response even though the URL is valid. Any ideas on why and how to fix? (I am able to access through my browser so not IP blocked)

Comment: Are you able to see this pdf URL in res.content object. If yes then you can use a regular expression to extract that url and use the urllib module( urllib.urlretrieve(url,filename)) to save pdf in hard disk.filename is the place where you want to save this PDF.

Comment: @SB07 Have edited to include res.content. How can I get the URL from it?

Comment: @apostrophe use an HTML parser such as beautifulsoup4?

Comment: First off, please consider the load you're puttin on sci-hubs servers. Be nice and add some throttling at least.

Comment: @KonstantinSchubert I will - the file currently only contains 1 DOI.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to extract the url. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-inside-a-string-in-python and here https://pythex.org/

Comment: Do you know the title of an article available on that site?

Comment: Or the DOI of one of them?

Comment: @BillBell I have a list of tiles & DOI's. Plan to first search using DOI's and if nothing comes up title.

Comment: @BillBell Sample DOI: 10.1016/j.anai.2016.01.022

Answer (score 1):

You can use [urllib library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) to access the html of the page and even download files, and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6883094/8439299) to find the url of the file you want to download.

```
import urllib
import re    

site = urllib.urlopen(".../index.html")
data = site.read() # turns the contents of the site into a string
files = re.findall('(http|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?(.pdf)', data) # finds the url

for file in files:
    urllib.urlretrieve(file, filepath) # "filepath" is where you want to save it
```

Comment: When I run this I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'`

Comment: @apostrophe are you using python 3? In that case, it's `import urllib.request
data = urllib.request.urlretrieve("file, filepath")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution:-

```
url = re.search('<iframe src = "\s*([^"]+)"', res.content)
url.group(1)
urllib.urlretrieve(url.group(1),'C:/.../Docs/test.pdf')
```

I ran it and it is working :)

**For Python 3:**

Change `urrlib.urlretrive` to `urllib.request.urlretrieve`

Comment: yes for that before these lines use
'import urllib
import re'

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a clunky code requiring selenium, requests and scrapy.

Use selenium to request either an article title or DOI.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver.get("http://sci-hub.io/")
>>> input_box = driver.find_element_by_name('request')
>>> input_box.send_keys('amazing scientific results\n')
```

An article by the title 'amazing scientific results' doesn't seem to exist. As a result, the site returns a diagnostic page in the browser window which we can ignore. It also puts 'http://sci-hub.io/' in webdriver's `current_url` property. This is helpful because it's an indication that the requested result isn't available.

```
>>> driver.current_url
'http://sci-hub.io/'
```

Let's try again, looking for the item that you know exists.

```
>>> driver.get("http://sci-hub.io/")
>>> input_box = driver.find_element_by_name('request')
>>> input_box.send_keys('DOI: 10.1016/j.anai.2016.01.022\n')
>>> driver.current_url
'http://sci-hub.io/10.1016/j.anai.2016.01.022'
```

This time the site returns a distinctive url. Unfortunately, if we load this using selenium we will get the pdf and, unless you're more able than I am, you will find it difficult to download this to a file on your machine.

Instead, I download it using the requests library. Loaded in this form you will find that the url of the pdf becomes visible in the HTML.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
```

To ferret out the url I use scrapy.

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=r.text)
>>> pdf_url = selector.xpath('.//iframe/@src')[0].extract()
```

Finally I use requests again to download the pdf so that I can save it to a conveniently named file on local storage.

```
>>> r = requests.get(pdf_url).content
>>> open('article_name', 'wb').write(r)
211853
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a combination of the answers above - namely **[SBO7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3596552/sb07)** & **[Roxerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8439299/roxerg).**

I use the following to extract the URL from the page and then download the PDF:

```
    res = requests.get('http://sci-hub.io/' + str(row['DOI']))
    useful = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html5lib").find_all("iframe")
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', str(useful[0]))
    response = requests.get(urls[0])
    with open("C:\\Users\\Sangeeta's\\Downloads\\ref\\" + str(row['ref']) + '.pdf', 'wb') as fw:
        fw.write(response.content)
```

***Note:*** This will not work for all articles - some link to webpages ([example](http://sci-hub.io/http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0151055)) and this doesn't correctly work for those.